# Angular - On click image, display Dialog Box with 3 Radio buttons

Tags: html, css, angular, dialog, radio-button

In my angular application I am trying to add functionality, when I click on Windows image a new Dialog window should appear with 3 radio buttons. I need help to add this functionality

Here is the stackblitz link

Link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvinp9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: which UI library you're using ?

Comment: Trying to achieve using Angular material or basic Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Angular Material. Followings are things you can do :

create a separate component  `DialogContentExampleDialog` with 3 input fields and   add it to the `entry component` section in the `app.module.ts`:

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [DialogContentExample, DialogContentExampleDialog],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [..],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

then in `app.component` do following :

```
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
   ...
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
}
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5lw2bt?file=src/app/dialog-content-example-dialog.html)

Comment: Do I need all imports mentioned in material-module.ts?  Can I directly import in main app.module?

Comment: no, you should only import the packages you need.

Comment: Okay, why create 2 html files? Can we combine them as one?

Comment: Ideally , You  should be creating separate components for maintaining separation of concern principle.

Comment: Okay I get your point, but incase if I want one html file then how should I modify openDialog() method?